# is it okay to use built-in tensorflow functions as activations of a neural net?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, would the following code not have an implementation error?

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = [1, 2, 3]
y_data = [1, 2, 3]

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="Y")

hypothesis = tf.maximum(tf.add(tf.mul(W, X), b),0)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)
_, cost_val = tf.Session.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
```

Note the in the above code, I used `tf.maximum(tf.add(tf.mul(W, X), b),0) as to which I'm not so sure of its implementability because I don't know tf.maximum can calculate backpropagation.

A more general question is that can any activation function constructed from built-in tensorflow functions be trained with backpropagation in tf.Session?

My question in other words, does every tensorflow math operation come with its gradient information?

Comment: I think [tf.nn.relu_layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu_layer) is what you want?

Comment: @xxi Not in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of it this way: given some arbitrary function can the gradient be computed? That would be no. It depends on the function and to some extent how the parts of which it is composed is implemented in tensorflow.

In particular, the cost in your code is just a squared error loss, its known to have a global minimum.

with some tweeks your code runs:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = [1, 2, 3]
y_data = [1, 2, 3]

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="Y")

hypothesis = tf.maximum(tf.add(tf.multiply(W, X), b),0)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

train_op = optimizer.minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    _, cost_val = sess.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict={X: x_data, Y: y_data})
    print(cost_val)

4.999
```